# Software initialization code at 0xFFFFFFF0H

Tags: x86, operating-system, cpu-architecture, boot, bios

Intel says after reset the processor is placed in real mode and the software initialization code starts at 0xFFFFFFF0H. My questions:

- If processor is in real-mode how can it acess the memory > 1MB (0xFFFFFFF0H)
- How this happens or what happens when RAM in < 4GB ( say 2GB)
- If the BIOS is mapped at 0x000FFFFFH why processor starts executing at 0xFFFFFFF0H

Please help me with these questions.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some document to link to or quote from? It sure sounds like a misunderstanding.

Comment: Intel Software developer Manual, System Programming Guide 3A Part 1, Page 9-20( 253668.pdf )

Comment: You need to read up on how segment registers work in real mode.  Effective address = CS << 4 + IP.

Comment: @Hans Passant:   real mode: max of {cs<<4 + IP } = 1MB.

Comment: No, it rolls over.  Otherwise the logic behind the A20 gate and the DOS "high memory" area.

Comment: @Hans So does that mean 0x100000000 would be 0x0

Comment: No, it means that, say, CS=0xffff and IP=0x10 will produce an effective bus address of 0.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an address of 0xF?

Comment: Related: [How is BIOS ROM accessible at 0xFFFFFFF0 if A20 line is disabled by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32415491)

Comment: I posted an answer on [How can the CPU start with reset vector 0xFFFFFFF0 even though it starts in 16-bit real mode?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27035) on retrocomputing.SE, a more recent duplicate of this.  At least one beginner found it more easily understandable than the answers here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the [Coreboot documentation](http://www.coreboot.org/Coreboot_v3):

> Whenever an x86 CPU wakes up after reset, it does it in Real Mode. This mode is limited to 1MiB address space and 64k offsets and the reset vector of the original 8086/88 was located at 0xFFFF0.
>
> As there was no change even if we run current processors like P3, these newer CPUs also feels like they where start at 0xF000:0xFFF0 after a reset. But they do not. The base of the code segment register is 0xFFFF0000 after reset, so the CPU generates a physical address of 0xFFFFFFF0 to the chipset. And the chipset is responsible to forward this area to the boot ROM. Its confusing: The CPU "thinks" it runs code at 0xF000:0xFFF0 but instead it uses code at 0xFFFFFFF0. The developers must have been tanked up when they realised this design into silicon.

So it seems the Intel documentation talks about the physical address as used "on the wire", i.e. when accessing the real bus. And this is independent of the CPU mode (the bus doesn't know or care about a CPU mode, it's the CPUs duty to translate these things).

Comment: When I run Qemu, I see that it starts at 0xFFFF0. Does it mean that Qemu is still agnostic about this fact that current CPUs on motherboards generate 0xFFFFFFF0? Or is it just that Qemu developers weren't tanked up and decided to go by the normal "Real mode" 8086/88 route?

Comment: This is the same kind of thing as https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode - a CS base other than what you could get by writing to CS (with a far jmp) in Real Mode.   Like you could do by switching to protected mode and back.

Answer (score 5):

To see your question in action you will need a hardware debugger.     And the proper documentation is from Intel, to quote: http://download.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/253668.pdf, section 9.1.4:

> The first instruction that is fetched and executed following a
>   hardware reset is  located at physical address FFFFFFF0H. This address
>   is 16 bytes below the  processor’s uppermost physical address. The
>   EPROM containing the software initialization code must be located at
>   this address.

This means BIOS ROM, FYI, not your normal RAM, ie, the content is hardwired.   And remember,  at this stage, RAM memory is not even setup, and VGA memory (which is different from RAM) is not even available and initialized.

> The address FFFFFFF0H is beyond the 1-MByte addressable
>   range of the processor  while in real-address mode. The processor is
>   initialized to this starting address as  follows. The CS register has
>   two parts: the visible segment selector part and the  hidden base
>   address part. In real-address mode, the base address is normally 
>   formed by shifting the 16-bit segment selector value 4 bits to the
>   left to produce a  20-bit base address. However, during a hardware
>   reset, the segment selector in the  CS register is loaded with F000H
>   and the base address is loaded with FFFF0000H. The  starting address
>   is thus formed by adding the base address to the value in the EIP 
>   register (that is, FFFF0000 + FFF0H = FFFFFFF0H). The first time the
>   CS register is loaded with a new value after a hardware reset, the 
>   processor will follow the normal rule for address translation in
>   real-address mode  (that is, [CS base address = CS segment selector *
>   16]). To insure that the base  address in the CS register remains
>   unchanged until the EPROM based software initialization code is
>   completed, the code must not contain a far jump or far call or  allow
>   an interrupt to occur (which would cause the CS selector value to be
>   changed)

During this time, the BIOS essentially is initializing the hardware and the memory itself, while still executing in real mode.   Then finally the VGA BIOS (which exists in your VGA card, addressable at 0xc700) is executed etc etc.   But this is going beyond the current question.   But the quoted remarks above essentially answered your question.

Comment: From the documentation you quoted: `CS register is loaded with F000H and the base address is loaded with FFFF0000H`. When its being added, it is `FFFF0000 + FFF0H = FFFFFFF0H`. How did `F000` become `FFF0` ? Shifting `F000` to left by 4 bits make it `F0000`, isnt it ? what am i missing ?

Comment: @JayAurabind: The CS base address is used directly, with no shift.  This is like [unreal mode](https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode), with a CS base that's not `cs << 4`.  `F000` didn't *become* `FFF0`; they were just loaded separately.  (Like you could do by switching to protected mode and having a GDT entry with that base for that selector value, then back to real mode).  That's how it can address memory far outside the low 1MiB - `FFFF0000H` is a linear address, not a seg:off with a missing `:`.

Answer (score 4):

> If processor is in real-mode how can it access the memory > 1MB (0xFFFFFFF0H)

Almost nothing inside the CPU cares about "CPU mode". When executing normal instructions; what actually matters are things like default code size, segment base, segment limit, segment type, etc., and the CPU mode is irrelevant. It's only things like segment register loads and interrupt handlers where CPU mode matters (in fact, other than paging, I'd wouldn't be surprised if the only things that care about CPU mode are things implemented in micro-code).

Because CPU mode is mostly irrelevant for normal instructions (and because things like default code size, segment base, segment limit, segment type, etc. are the only things that actually matter); at power on or reset the CPU can set "abnormal" values (values that aren't normally possible for the CPU mode) into segment registers and the rest of the CPU won't care. Specifically; it can do "`CS.base_address = 0xFFFF0000`" (which isn't possible for real mode where a CS segment register load would do "`CS.base_address = 16_bit_CS.value << 4`").

The end result is that all memory accesses that involve CS (and pass segment limit checks) end up going to the (linear) address "`0xFFFF0000 + offset`" even though the CPU is in "real mode" and even though this isn't normally possible for real mode.

Note that in real mode addresses are not limited to 1 MiB. For example, if you load 0xFFFF into a segment register then CPU will set that segment register's hidden info to "segment.base = 0x000FFFF0" and addresses using that segment will end up with (linear) addresses from 0x000FFFF0 to 0x0010FFEF. This is why (when 80286 was released) we needed the "A20 gate" for compatibility with ancient software (to force the 20th address bit to be zero without the CPU knowing).

Also note that while "`CS.base_address = 0xFFFF0000`" isn't normal for real mode; software can switch to protected mode and load a "code size = 16-bit, segment limit 
 64 KiB, segment base = 0xFFFF000" descriptor into CS; and then switch back to real mode without reloading CS. The end result would be the same "abnormal CS base" that the CPU sets up at power on or reset.

Of course (regardless of how an abnormal value got into CS.base) any normal CS segment register load that's executed in real mode will cause "CS.base" to be set to a normal value; so firmware would have to be ensure that no CS segment register loads occur while it's executing in "real mode" at the abnormal address.

> How this happens or what happens when RAM in < 4GB ( say 2GB)

The physical address space is used for RAM, and ROM, and memory mapped devices. The ROM (and not RAM) will be just below the "4 GiB" address. For example, if the ROM is 2 MiB, then it'd be in the physical address range from 0xFFE00000 to 0xFFFFFFFF. Note that at power on  firmware can not use RAM (it has to figure out what type and size of memory modules are installed and configure the memory controller to suit, before it can expect RAM to work).

> If the BIOS is mapped at 0x000FFFFFH why processor starts executing at 0xFFFFFFF0H

Originally (80286 and older CPUs) the BIOS actually was mapped at 0x000FFFFF. For (some) 80386 and later CPUs this is only emulated for compatibility reasons. Instead;  the firmware copies a small piece of itself from ROM (in the area ending at physical address 0xFFFFFFFF) to RAM (in the area ending at physical address 0x000FFFFF); and then configures the memory controller so that writes made to this area of RAM are ignored (so that memory controller doesn't forward these writes to the RAM chips).

Note that for "pure UEFI" systems (not including "hybrid BIOS + UEFI" systems), there's no reason for firmware to set up the "legacy BIOS area" ending at physical address 0x000FFFFF; and RAM in this area may be usable RAM (configured as "allow writes" in memory controller, etc). In the same way, the other legacy areas (for VGA and device ROMs) aren't needed for "pure UEFI" either; and in theory  (for a computer with 2 GiB of RAM or less) there's no reason (except for SMM stealing a little) you can't just have single contiguous area of normal RAM from 0x00000000 to 0x7FFFFFFF.

Comment: I think on the original 286 IBM ATs the top 4 address lines were held high until the first FAR JMP at which point they were pulled low.

Comment: "the firmware copies a small piece of itself from ROM (in the area ending at physical address 0xFFFFFFFF) to RAM (in the area ending at physical address 0x000FFFFF)" this seems to contradict what this [article](https://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/booting-an-intel-architecture-system-par/232300699?pgno=3) says: "Intel chipsets usually come with memory aliasing capabilities that allow access to memory below 1 MB to be routed to or from DRAM or nonvolatile storage located just under 4 GB."

Comment: @wmjdgla: The article is right (chipsets do have the ability to route accesses in different ranges below 1 MiB to system bus instead of RAM, it is slow, and "shadowing in RAM" can be used to speed it up); but "shadowing in RAM" is mostly always done and that ability mostly isn't used (except briefly when initializing device ROMs on devices not built into firmware/motherboard - e.g. PCI video cards, PCI RAID controller cards, etc).

Comment: But it is the firmware that performs the shadowing, so the system must execute some non-shadowed firmware code first. Before the firmware switches to protected/long mode, the system can only access 1MB of memory. So doesn't this mean that the non-shadowed firmware code, which was mapped to the high memory area (so that the reset vector could be placed at 0xFFFF FFF0), must be aliased to the first 1MB of memory?

Comment: @wmjdgla: It's probably easier to think of it as 2 separate pieces of firmware - the "platform initialization code" (ending at 0xFFFFFFFF) that does lots of stuff including setting up shadowing for the other piece, and the "legacy BIOS run-time code" (ending at 0x000FFFFF) that is shadowed (after the first piece set it up). Of course for "hybrid BIOS plus UEFI" you'd have 3 pieces (the same initialization code, followed by either BIOS or UEFI run-time environment depending on firmware settings).

Comment: @wmjdgla: "Platform initialization" probably switches to protected mode or long mode extremely early (before configuring RAM/memory controllers), and then switches back to real mode just before passing control to the "legacy BIOS run-time" part. In that way (mostly) only the "legacy BIOS run-time" part uses real mode.